# When is key/value caching on Heroku worthwhile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, heroku

**Background:**

I have a web service which takes in input of 1 to 20 objects, and then performs an operation on each that takes roughly 100-300ms. The results of that operation are valid on average for one hour, and the output is a hash of strings and integers. The average request has 5 objects, thus a response time of roughly 1000ms. I am expecting a pretty low cache hit rate until the service picks up traction--let's call it a 10% hit rate for now.

My application is hosted on Heroku, and for the purposes of this question, I do not wish to move it.

**What I've Tried**

I started with the free offering from IronCache (through the Heroku add-on), and did some very rough tests. A put() and get() request take roughly 20-40ms for simple objects. There is no support for batch operations, so assuming a 100% cache miss, this would add 20-40ms per object to my response. In my average case for 5 objects, that is roughly 150ms extra.

IronCache did not support batched operations, but it seems like that would solve my issue.

**My Question**

Given this profile, is it worthwhile to use a hosted caching (key/value) store on Heroku? If so, which?

Comment: Did you read the recent revelation about rails performance on Heroku?

Comment: About routing performance? Seems tangential to the issue above. The service runs fine on a single dyno with 4 Unicorn workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with MemCachier, an add-on for Heroku which offers a 25MB free tier. They use Dalli as their Ruby library, which supports get_multi, and a multi function which takes a block and defers sending until the end of the block.

Answer (score 0):

If batched operations will make caching worth while for you, you should use redis, It supports them.